# Stuck on column was specified multiple times...can't find the workaround for no alias on WHERE

Tags: sql

So I have the following query that returns "The column 'ReceiverNo' was specified multiple times for location_4" error.  I'm not an SQL expert but I know you cannot use an alias in a WHERE clause but I need to ensure those 2 similarly named columns match values in order to update the correct Estim row.  Is there a work around for this that anyone is aware of?  I know this has been asked but I found nothing quite this similar...

```
With location_4 as (
  SELECT TOP (1) ReceiverDET.ReceiverNo, ReceiverDET.PartNo, Estim.User_Text4, 
  Receiver.ReceiverNo, Receiver.ReceiveDate
  FROM Estim, ReceiverDET, Receiver
  WHERE Receiver.ReceiverNo = ReceiverDET.ReceiverNo
  AND Estim.PartNo = ReceiverDet.PartNo
  ORDER BY Receiver.ReceiveDate DESC
  )
 UPDATE location_4
SET User_Text4 ='Not in Location'
WHERE User_Text4 = ''
```

If the above columns from the different tables do not match values it does not work, and there has to be a way...  I've tried 100 different ways so far.  When I remove the update statement it works fine and displays the proper row every time, it just breaks trying to actually use update.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Location_4 is not a table, it's a temporary data set.  You cannot update it.

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Comment: @Andrew MSSQL, the tables are a bit of a mess but it's a 3rd party app

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I know, and It works perfectly fine actually without the duplicate column name in WHERE but I must ensure the Receiver.ReceiverNo and ReceiverDET.ReceiverNo match values to get the correct table row to update.

Comment: This is all sorts of funky, and I'd be concerned it's not deterministic.  But if your CTE has top 1 in it, you don't need a where clause in your update.

Comment: Please update your post with sample data, and your desired result. Are you trying to change the value only in the output of your query, or update it in the base table?

Comment: @Andrew Yes it is and it is extremely convoluted.  I'll do my best to whip up a sample but there's a lot going on.  It does need the WHERE however because of the way the app displays Estim results within Receivers in app.  It dynamically shows partNo's from the Estim table which is has to reference the ReceiverNo's from the 2 other tables and also match Partno's from 2 tables or it ends populating the User_Text4 field incorrectly.  Don't ask...it's stupid.  This is a 3rd party EPR app so it doesn't help that I cannot just see/edit the source code because I am a PHP guy, not SQL obviously.

Comment: A CTE is not updateable if it returns data from multiple base tables. Each column must, as indicated by the error message, have a unique name.

Comment: @Stu Thanks, I just wondered if there was a workaround, I will find another way then.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: A CTE is not required here, simply write a normal `update` statement against table `Estim` probably with some correlating `exists` criteria or joins using proper *join* syntax.